# Как создать DependencyProperty для фигуры?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть контрол. Я хочу чтобы в нем отображалась фигурка и текст. Фигурку, цвет и обводку пользователь может задать самостоятельно, по умолчанию должен быть красный кружок с черной границей.

Пытаюсь использовать для контейнера фигуры `Path`, Фигуркой по умолчанию будет `EllipseGeometry`, однако не знаю как забиндить ее в `Path.Data`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте в контрол свойство зависимости типа `Geometry` и задайте для него значение по умолчанию:

```
    public Geometry Data
    {
        get { return (Geometry)GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }

    public static DependencyProperty DataProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Data", typeof (Geometry), typeof (MyControl), new PropertyMetadata(new EllipseGeometry(new Rect(new Size(100, 100)))));
```

А в разметке контрола привяжитесь к этому свойству:

```
<Path Data="{Binding Data, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MyControl}}}" Fill="Red" />
```

Теперь можно использовать:

```
<local:MyControl />
<!-- или -->
<local:MyControl>
    <local:MyControl.Data>
        <RectangleGeometry Rect="10, 10, 50, 50"/>
    </local:MyControl.Data>
</local:MyControl>
```

Comment: Есть несколько вопросов. Можно ли в значении по умолчанию указать `EllipseGeometry` из ресурсов? Еще в данном случае пользователь будет задавать геометрию и она будет отрисовываться с нужным цветом (точнее кистью) заливки и обводки. А если пользователь захочет вставить вместо геометрии картинку? Ему придется перестраивать шаблон контрола. А можно ли упростить ему задачу? Для этого нужно свойство `Data` делать типа `object`, а затем проверять что в него передали? В коде это сделать не сложно, а как на счет xaml разметки?

Comment: EllipseGeometry можно взять и из ресурсов. А вот можно ли сделать предложенную вами штуку с использованием object и выбором типа в разметке, я не знаю. Возможно, если повозиться с конвертерами и триггерами что-нибудь получится. В любом случае, я бы предложил вам написать три контрола: один с базовой частью и два для отображения изображения или геометрии.